# How to change names inside filter for booleans in datatable in shiny?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatable, dt

I have a datatable in Shiny where I use the `filter` option. When I want to filter a boolean column, I can choose `true` and `false`. I would like to rename these values. So instead of `true` and `false`, it should show `yes` and `no`.

The displayed column entries are not `TRUE` or `FALSE` but checkboxes. This is important, that's why I add it to the code example.

I had the idea to convert the booleans to factors. Then the filter shows `yes` and `no`. However, in this case all checkboxes are checked, so this doesn't work. I commented out the line that does the converting in the code below. If there is a solution without this converting step it would be nice.

As I didn't find any option to change the values, I guess, this can only be accomplished with JavaScript code. Unfortunately, I am not really familiar with JavaScript. I hopse someone call help me here.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

set.seed(43)
data <- data.frame(A = rnorm(10),
                   B = letters[1:10],
                   C = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10, TRUE))

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table_id")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table_id <- renderDT(
    data %>%
      # mutate(C = as_factor(if_else(C == TRUE, "yes", "no"))) %>%
      datatable(filter = "top",
                options = list(
                  columnDefs = list(
                    list(
                      targets = c(3),
                      render = JS(
                        "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
                        "  if(type === 'display'){",
                        "    return data ? '<input type=\"checkbox\" disabled checked/>' : '<input type=\"checkbox\" disabled/>';",
                        "  }",
                        "  return data;",
                        "}"
                      )
                    ))
                )
      )
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your factor `C` in your data.frame will pass values of either "yes" or "no"; however, your JS function is checking `data` to see if it is `TRUE` or `FALSE`. If you compare `data` with "yes", then the "yes" will be considered `TRUE` and "no" will be considered `FALSE`. Let me know if this produces the desired behavior.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

set.seed(43)
data <- data.frame(A = rnorm(10),
                   B = letters[1:10],
                   C = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10, TRUE))

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table_id")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table_id <- renderDT(
    data %>%
      mutate(C = as_factor(if_else(C == TRUE, "yes", "no"))) %>%
      datatable(filter = "top",
                options = list(
                  columnDefs = list(
                    list(
                      targets = c(3),
                      render = JS(
                        "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
                        "  if(type === 'display'){",
                        "    return data == \"yes\" ? '<input type=\"checkbox\" disabled checked/>' : '<input type=\"checkbox\" disabled/>';",
                        "  }",
                        "  return data;",
                        "}"
                      )
                    ))
                )
      )
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```